# `id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment

Tags: mysql, sql

This field type:

```
`id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment
```

...accepts does not accept value ('') on one server/database while another server/database accepts it.

Is there some kind of inconsistency somewhere in the setup? I tried different server versions - 5.1.52, 5.1.57, 5.5. How to make them consistent?

Comment: Why do you try to pass particular value to it?! It is already autoincrement, just skip it - it will be filled automatically. Btw, empty string is not an integer - why to put it there then? It is supposed that you fuel your car with gasoline, and not with water. Have you ever fueled it with water? Nope? But why with rdmbs you want to fill field with *wrong* value type?

Comment: `DEFAULT` and `NULL` are known placeholders to trigger default constraints...

Answer (score 1):

if your field is of  **autoincrement** type then you should simply **skip** it.

for example
 you need to insert a comment where **id** is 'autoincrement' field then:

> $add="INSERT INTO comments (comment, author_id, article_id) VALUES
>           ('".$comment."',".$authorID.",".$articleID." )";
>
> $result=mysql_query($add)
>
> ...